# Google showing the wrong title tag for my website

Tags: google-search, page-title

I have a website, and just recently I saw that Google shows a entirely different title tag for one of my pages.

I'm selling websites, and therefore I have a page where people can what services I can provide, and how much it will cost. I have then created a title tag with a simple sentence saying something like: "An overview of services and prices at (My website)"

Pretty simple, nothing fancy.

But, when I search for my website, via site:website.com in Google, every other page on my website has the correct title tag, but this one page just have: "Prices - MyWebsite.com"

Anyone have an idea why this is so?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The js included at the bottom of my page:

```
<div class="md-overlay"></div>
<script src="/js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="/js/modalEffects.js"></script>

<script>
    var polyfilter_scriptpath = '/js/';
</script>
<script src="/js/cssParser.js"></script>
<script src="/js/css-filters-polyfill.js"></script>
```

Which I have from [Nifty Modal Window](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/25/nifty-modal-window-effects/).
Don't know if this has something to do with it.

Comment: Because you have made an exception for that page and changed the content of the tag. What CMS are you using?

Comment: from the large quantities of relevant code examples and addreses you've provided, I'm 100% confident in saying that the problem is due to the alien mothership in orbit interfering with the higgs bosons in your server's secondary harddrive platter.

Comment: No CMS. It's pure HTML, which some javscript etc. on it.
The reason I didn't include code or such is because it's a title-tag :) It's just the same on every other page, which works. So I was kinda thinking it would be a Google problem tbh.

But, in the end of my page I have some js included, which I do not have on the other pages. I will edit my main post so you can see what.

Answer (score -2):

Google algorithms generate thee alternative titles so that your page is no longer constrained with having just the one title for all the different queries your page ranks for.

This has the nice side effect of making the result look more relevant to our searchers and...
On average, the alternative titles increase the clickthrough rate on the results, i.e. more traffic for you.

The  tag is still a primary source for titles we show so all our advice about make them concise and useful and enticing still very much apply. Keep an eye on the HTML Suggestions page in the Diagnostics section in Webmaster Tools for title suggestions.